# How do I extract all values of a given attribute and put them into an array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Ruby object that looks like this:

```
- !ruby/object:Foo
  attributes:
    updated: 2013-07-30 13:30:21.589221000 Z
    bar: 3
- !ruby/object:Statistic
  attributes:
    updated: 2013-07-30 13:30:28.017951000 Z
    bar: 8
- !ruby/object:Statistic
  attributes:
    updated: 2013-07-30 13:30:39.514180000 Z
    bar: 1
```

The object comes from an ActiveRecord query.

I would like to get an array of all the `bar`s in this object i.e.

```
[3, 8, 1]
```

Is there some slick way of doing this in Ruby?

Comment: not sure about the specific object you have there. But something like `list.map {|o| o.attributes[:bar]}` should work.

Comment: @ale what is the class of this object?

Comment: Maybe that "Ruby object" is a YAML file you want to parse?

Comment: No, it's just a YAML representation of the collection of objects.

Comment: This how the object is created: `@foo = Statistic.joins(:type).where("blah1 = ? AND blah2 = ?",params[:blah_id], "some string").select("updated, count")`.  I need to use both the `updated` and `count` fields in my view but for part of the view I only want `count`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want one attribute from an ActiveRecord query, you can use [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck):

```
Foo.all.pluck(:bar)
```

Comment: I think you'd want Foo.pluck(:bar)

Comment: Either would work, you can string relations together and add `#pluck` to the end I believe. From the example in the Rails Guides: `Client.where(active: true).pluck(:id)`

Comment: I think where brings back a ActiveRecord::Relation whereas all brings back a true Array which doesn't support pluck. I'm on 3.2.13 and I'm a little surprised about behavior.